# Is there anyway to enable MultiSelect in the StyledTextCtrl

Tags: wxwidgets, text-editor, textmate, scintilla, wxruby

I've noticed that the StyledTextControl (Scintilla basically) in wxWidgets has a great feature that allows multi-selections of text, just like TextMate. However wxRuby doesn't seem to have the function calls to support that feature. I'm wonder if there is a way to enable it or if there might be a way I could rewrite that wrapper to include that function.

It seems strange that they would purposely omit that since they are seemingly pretty exhaustive on most functions calls. Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to write an open source TextMate clone in Ruby and it's gonna be pretty hard without MultiSelect, I could probably hack something together but it'd be ugly. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't write which version of wxWidgets you are using, but AFAIK only the 2.x versions of the Scintilla library support MultiSelect, which isn't available in stable wxWidgets. wxWidgets 2.8.10 uses [Scintilla version 1.70](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/browser/wxWidgets/branches/WX_2_8_BRANCH/contrib/src/stc/scintilla/README.txt). The SVN trunk uses [version 1.75](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/browser/wxWidgets/trunk/src/stc/scintilla/README.txt).